# Communicate between two MainWindow() in Qt

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt

My app, in Qt, consists in 2 different windows (but both inherited from QtGui.QMainWIndow), and I am wondering how to communicate between them. Moreover, does using multiple QMainWindow is generally a good approach?

Comment: Have you heard of [Signals and Slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) in Qt ?

Comment: Yes, I often use it. Should-I build a class inherited from QApplication whose window1 and window2 (still inherited from QMainWindow) are attributes? To summerize, I am looking for the best way to handle multiple windows app in Qt.

Comment: Signal/slots, or create a class that knows all main windows and handles the interaction between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect signals and slots between the two window classes when you instantiate them.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window1 = MyMainWindow1()
    window1.show()

    window2 = MyMainWindow2()
    window2.show()

    # connect signals to communicate between windows
    window1.someSignal.connect(window2.someSlot)
    window2.anotherSignal.connect(window1.anotherSlot)

    app.exec()
```

`QMainWindow` is designed to be used as the main application window; it simplifies the addition of common window features like toolbars and menus. However, I don't think there is any harm in having multiple instances.

You can also just use any`QWidget`:

```
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()    # note that no parent is given
window.show()
```

Comment: That's what I've done but in a upper class inherited from QApplication.